# Change the icon of Jtree Root Node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Below is the code i have created a Jtree with root Node "Data Generation..

```
rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Data Generation");
treeModel =new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
tree = new JTree(treeModel);            
tree.setEditable(true);
```

I have changed the icon images for the leaf node

```
childNode=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(existingtagnames.get(len).toString());
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) tree.getCellRenderer();
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(Generate_Explorer.class.getResource("/org/qmon/generate/Images/Leaf Node.png"));
renderer.setLeafIcon(imageIcon);
tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

I dont know how to do for the Root node.. i searched in the internet but unable to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use these two methods on the renderer, it should set your icon on non-leaf nodes.

```
setClosedIcon(Icon newIcon)

setOpenIcon(Icon icon)
```