# how to set different icon to the ROOT of JTree in java

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Root
  - List item
  - List item

> for Root `icanA` and for `TreeNode IconB` how can i.

i am working with this code:

```
   public static DefaultMutableTreeNode createNodes() {
      DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new 
      DefaultMutableTreeNode("Java");DefaultMutableTreeNode j2se = new 
      DefaultMutableTreeNode("J2SE");
      DefaultMutableTreeNode j2ee = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("J2EE");
      DefaultMutableTreeNode j2me = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("J2ME");
      j2se.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("http://java.sun.com/j2se/"));
      j2ee.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("http://java.sun.com/j2ee/"));
      j2me.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("http://java.sun.com/j2me/"));
      root.add(j2se);
      root.add(j2ee);
      root.add(j2me);
return root;
}
```

Comment: I'd start with [How to Use Trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) as the root node is nothing special and the means for customising it would be the same for customising any other node

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296314/change-the-icon-of-jtree-root-node

Comment: Thank you sir, i will use it.